# SQL Server: populating rows between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization

I'm trying to figure out an optimal way to populate missing rows between couple of monthly dates.

Here is how my input data looks like:

```
ID    Date        Value
100   8/1/2011    1
100   10/1/2011   2
103   8/1/2011    3
```

Here is how my output needs to look like:

```
ID    Date       Value
100   8/1/2011   1
100   9/1/2011   1
100   10/1/2011  2
100   11/1/2011  2
100   12/1/2011  2    ...till current date
```

```
103   8/1/2011   3
103   9/1/2011   3
103   10/1/2011  3
103   11/1/2011  3
103   12/1/2011  3   ...till current date
```

Generating the dates is not an issue, however, not sure how to copy over the value column across the date ranges without using for loops which is pretty slow.

Any thoughts are highly appreciated !

Comment: The squiggle brace icon `{}` in the post editor will format a section as code, saving you from the madness that is hundreds of `&nbsp;` that never quite align.

Comment: You should have a look at how the formatting here works to not have to do all those `nbsp;` like Goat already said. Here's a link to the formatting help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code For now I changed your post to the standard formatting, hope that was okay for you.

Comment: thank you for formatting it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and a self-join to create a range of dates, then join that to your date table:

```
;with  cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Dt) RN
               FROM Table1)
      ,cte2 AS (SELECT a.ID
                      ,a.dt BegDt
                      ,ISNULL(b.dt,GETDATE()) EndDt
                      ,a.Value
                FROM cte a
                LEFT JOIN cte b
                   ON a.RN = b.RN -1
                   AND a.ID = b.ID)
      ,dt AS (SELECT CAST('2011-08-01' AS DATE) Dt
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT DATEADD(month,1,dt)
              FROM dt
              WHERE dt < '2011-12-01') --GETDATE() for current
SELECT a.ID,b.Dt,a.Value
FROM cte2 a
JOIN dt b
  ON b.dt >= a.BegDt
   AND b.dt < a.EndDT
ORDER BY ID, DT
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b3115/22/0)